# NASM - Place 8 bits of data in a specific place within a 32-bit register

Tags: nasm, cpu-registers

Suppose I have some 8-bit data in the bl register, and I want to place it in the rightmost 8 bits of eax. Is there a way to do that directly? I assume the answer is very simple, I just haven't found it.

Obviously I could just multiply ebx by FFFFFFh, but then I have to rearrange my registers as the result will go into eax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "rightmost" in the same way as the Intel documentation, e.g. you refer to bits 7-0 , then what's wrong with `mov al, bl`?

Comment: Then a simple `mov al, bl` and a `shl eax, 8` will move the data to bits 8-15. `shl eax, 16` will move it to 16-23, and `shl eax, 24` will move it to 24-31. :) You might want to `xor eax, eax` beforehand.

Comment: is there a way to do it if I already have information in bits 24-31 that I want to keep there?

Comment: Sure. You'll need to use another register in that case, though. I'll use `ecx` here. `xor ecx, ecx`, `mov cl, bl`, `shl ecx, 8` and `or eax, ecx` will get your data from `bl` into bits 15-8 of `eax` without modifying any other data in `eax`.